# Android : Need help in an Activity extending ListActivity

Tags: java, android, listactivity

I have an activity with a listview of installed apps and other items, but i have created layout programmatically, the adapter needs to be used in a ListActivity & it is necessary to give listview this id `"@android:id/list` in xml but i have no xml used. When i add a listview to layout, it force closes the app. Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Yeah, post the stack here. Btw how about not using ListActivity. Use normal Activity and maybe easier.

Answer (score 1):

if you give  @android:id/list as id use this

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

(in ListActivity)

for other ids

`ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourownid);` (in normal activity)

Answer (score 0):

If you extend your class with ListActivity you should have an xml file with listview having and id `@android:id/list`, thats the default implementation of listactivity. If you want to do it programatically extend an activity for your class

Answer (score 0):

Use code below:

```
       String[] array={"Android","iOS","Windows","Linux","Unix"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Hope this will help you.